# How to increase font size on very large screen sizes 2560 x 1600

Tags: css

I am using Bootstrap 5 which already varies the font size across all displays but I'm finding that it is not setting the font large enough on very large screen sizes (example 2560 x1600).  I'm looking for the easiest way to modify my CSS to increase the font size proportionally without using media queries if possible and without having to touch each page on the site.

I tried the following CSS which works, but I'm using the font size classes throughout the site (fs-1, fs-3 etc...).  My CSS below does not impact these.

```
    @media (min-width: 2001px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 2000px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 3rem;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: calc(1vw + 2.5rem);
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: calc(1vw + 2rem);
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: calc(1vw + 1.5rem);
        }

        h4 {
            font-size: calc(1vw + 1rem);
        }

        h5 {
            font-size: calc(1vw + .5rem);
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: calc(1vw + .3rem);
        }

        p {
            font-size: calc(1vw + .3rem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `vw` or `vh` units? c.f.: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Generally the approach for scaling fonts is to use relative font units everywhere, and then set a top level size (e.g. on `body`) that can be customised based on whatever you think is relevant (window size, user settings, etc)

Comment: If those classes have rem units you can just set e.g. body {font size: 50px;} (or maybe it is html{}?) for certain window dimensions. Then all rem units will be calculated from this value.